# send <style> info from custom server asp element

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I want send to output CSS info in style blocks

```
      protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
      ...
      output.Write("<style> .... ");
    }
```

But this block cant be nested in div block .I must place it in head.How can I do it or is there another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`this.Page.Header.Stylesheet.CreateStyleRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.istylesheet.createstylerule.aspx) method lets you add styles to the `<head>`. However, the CSS attributes that you can specify are limited to those supported by the [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.aspx) class. (You can derive your own class from `Style` if you need additional attributes.)

C# example:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    // Create a Style object for the body of the page.
    Style bodyStyle = new Style();

    bodyStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    bodyStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;

    // Add the style rule named bodyStyle to the header 
    // of the current page. The rule is for the body HTML element.
    this.Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(bodyStyle, null, "body");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Derive from `System.Web.UI.Control` directly and override the `Render` method, instead of deriving from (what I assume is) `System.Web.IO.WebControls.WebControl`.