# send dynamic css from custom asp net server control

Tags: asp.net, css, custom-controls

How can render dynamic css from custom control based on user settings?I read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184276/send-style-info-from-custom-server-asp-element) article but it is not I want.Style class hasnt got all css properties and direct write style isnt good approach.

Comment: You can set any CSS property you want as a control property and render it in the control based on what the user wants? Can you be more specific on what you want to style?

Comment: yes,I want to render user settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply style not to one element you can do this:

```
 protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<style type='text/css'> .x { border-style:solid }</style>"));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If your styles change on a per user basis, and you want full control over what is rendered, writing the styles yourself is a perfectly good approach.

This is how you can do it:

```
    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        var styleStr = "{color:red}";
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, "style");
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, styleStr);
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    }
```